# Out of range value for column in MySQL float column

Tags: mysql, firedac, c++builder-10.3-rio

I have a MySQL database with a table containing many columns declared as `float` type, e.g.`TgPhi_L1_Min FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,`. The table is filled by a program written in C++Builder 10.3 using FireDAC (`TFDQuery`) that collects data from a measuring device. The code responsible for that looks like this:

```cpp
FDQuery_InsertData->Open("SELECT * FROM {id measurements_general} WHERE 1=2");
FDQuery_InsertData->Insert();
FDQuery_InsertData->FieldByName("meter_id")->AsInteger = MeterId;
FDQuery_InsertData->FieldByName("cfg_id")->AsInteger = ConfigId;
FDQuery_InsertData->FieldByName("date_time")->AsDateTime = DateTime;
FDQuery_InsertData->FieldByName("insert_date_time")->AsDateTime = Now();
for (auto i = 0; i < DescriptorsGeneral.List->Count; i++)
{
    if (IsNan(Data[DescriptorsGeneral.Indexes[i]]) || IsInfinite(Data[DescriptorsGeneral.Indexes[i]]))
            continue;
    FDQuery_InsertData->FieldByName(DescriptorsGeneral.List->Strings[i])->AsSingle = Data[DescriptorsGeneral.Indexes[i]]; //Data is passed as a parameter to this function, float *Data;
}
FDQuery_InsertData->Post();
```

Everything goes fine, until someday a measuring device sent a value which is the maximum `float` value of `0x7F7FFFFF`. It shouldn't be a problem, but I got an exception

> First chance exception at $772A3642. Exception class EMySQLNativeException with message '[FireDAC][Phys][MySQL] Out of range value for column 'TgPhi_L1_Min' at row 1'. Process Meter_Server.exe (12796).

Trying to understand what happened, I turned on FireDAC's monitor, and it turns out that the value inserted into the `INSERT` statement indeed exceeds the `float` range i.e. `3.4028235E38`. What I find more surprising is that numbers passed to the `INSERT` statement differ in precision, although all are declared the same way (MySQL `float`, FireDAC `single`), eg `0.98364758`,  `0`, `3.4028235E38`, `-3.4028235E38`, `0`, `3.4028235E38`, `-3.4028235E38`, `29.885546`.

The parameters of fetching columns by `TFDQuery` are: `Col add [Index=86, SrcName="TgPhi_L1", SrcType=Single, SrcSize=0, SrcPrec=12, SrcScale=31, Type=Single, Size=0, Prec=12, Scale=31]`.

I tried with `FormatOptions`: `CheckPrecision` and `Round2Scale`, I added my own mapping rules setting `ScaleMin` and `PrecMin`, but none of it affected values in the `INSERT` statement sent to the database by FireDAC.

Can anyone help me solve this problem? what I am doing wrong?

**EDITED:**

I'm confused, of course when I prepare a proper string manually, as @GarrGodfrey suggested, it works, but it doesn't work with `TFDQuery` in the way I did it. `TFDQuery` knows that the field is the `single` type, and finally always converts and rounds the values to single precision. The problem is, the `single` type fields have a `Precision` property set to 7, which complies with the `float` standard. But in MySQL I'm not sure, this is where I'm lost.

In C++, the following two numbers are treated as equal:

```cpp
float x = 3.4028235E38; 
float y = 3.402823466385288E38;
```

I think, this is because `y` has much more precision and is rounded. In MySQL, these are two different numbers: `x` is out of range and `y` is not, why?

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_float`()
begin
    declare x float;
    declare y float;
    set x = 3.4028235E38;
    set y = 3.402823466385288E38;
    select x, y;
end
```

Comment: shouldn't your "IsInfinite" function be catching that? Presumably that's what is meant by the max float value coming in.

Comment: Till now I thought it should be enough but according to the float standard, infinity has different notation and in my case this is a correct number, so IsInfinite function doesn't catch that. I suppose that here it's about precision/rounding.

Comment: Yeah, appears the problem occurs converting float -> string to send as a SQL value. The resulting string, when converted back to a double can no longer fit in a float

Comment: firedac probably doesn't care if you give it a float or a string.  You could try formatting yourself and passing the string instead of the actual float.